# confusion past tense and present tense

Tags: tense

name is usually unchangeable, so

1. I forgot what her name is
2. I forgot what her name was

#1 sentence is correct sentence? or #2?
if both make sense, what's the difference?

Comment: The dirty tip is to avoid the issue. "I forgot her name".

Answer (score 1):

Names can be changed easily in many parts of the globe but that doesn't matter here. What matters is if she's alive.
Both are correct if she is, whether you use a present or a past tense depends on the situation and sometimes on your preference.

> I forgot what her name is

Means you can't remember her name and she's still alive. This is also used when she's present while you're talking about her, for example you're talking with your friend while looking at her from across the room.

> I forgot what her name was

Means you can't remember her name, she can be alive or dead, but even if she's alive, she's usually not present while you're talking about her. Of course you can still use it if she is, that's when your preference comes in. If you're talking about events in the past while looking at her from across the room, you may use this instead of the first. It's technically up to you.

Only the second is correct if she's dead though because you can use only the past tenses while talking about a dead person.

The only exceptions are sentences like

> She is dead.

But obviously here you're not talking about something she had or did but her current state. Also

> She was dead.

is also correct, but in this case you pair it with something else, like

> By the time I arrived, she was already dead.